# .Net Core 2.1 API detect session expiry

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, session-state

I am writing C#.Net Core 2.1 APIs with Authorization enabled. I need to detect session expiry in .Net Core 2.1, in order to log them later.

Authorization mechanism used

```
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
  Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new System.Security.Claims.Claim[]
  {
    new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,userFromRepo.Id.ToString()),
    new System.Security.Claims.Claim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name,userFromRepo.FullName)
  }),
  Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12),
  SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature)
};
```

Is there a way in the API to manually check if session is expired?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information. What authorization mechanism do you using?

Comment: Updated my post accordingly